# Creating new team with graph api missing response

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I am creating a new MS-Teams team with the C# library for the graph api.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/3.35.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Until now I use the "create team from group" version, since the direct creation of teams from templates wasn't supported when I initially started the project.
Since this includes the overhead of manually creating a group, and is more error prone (mailNickname collision, timings) I wanted to move to the new template api from the link.

The problem is I need at least the Id from the created team.

```
var newTeam = await graphClient.Teams
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(team);
```

Executing the code from the docs only returns null.
Since this is a long running operation, the response only contains, a location where i can get the data after it is finished.

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Content-Type: application/json
Location: /teams('dbd8de4f-5d47-48da-87f1-594bed003375')/operations('3a6fdce1-c261-48bc-89de- 1cfef658c0d5')
Content-Location: /teams('dbd8de4f-5d47-48da-87f1-594bed003375')
Content-Length: 0
```

Is there a way to access the response data without completely abandoning the use of the C# library?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reaching out. To access the team, send a GET to the teams endpoint, passing in the id in the Location. You should wait >30 seconds between checks. You should be able to use the SDK to send this request:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var team = await graphClient.Teams["dbd8de4f-5d47-48da-87f1-594bed003375"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

Please see [teamsAsyncOperation](http://Please%20see%20documentation%20here:%20for%20more%20information:%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamsasyncoperation?view=graph-rest-1.0) documentation for more information.

Let me know if this helps and if you have further questions.